# Best IDE / Plugin for develop Solidity

Tags: ide, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am developing some complex solidity smartcontracts (using some external libraries such as Oraclize). 
The think is that the IDE that I am using for the moment [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false) and [Oraclize IDE](http://dapps.oraclize.it/browser-solidity/) dosen't fit with the requirments that I want, I need:

- To compile, deploy and test a smartcontract that can use Oraclize library
- Have the files in local and be allowed to use a private github repository
- Compile the contracts only when clicking Ctrl + S
- Have a desktop environment (Like IntellIJ or Atom)

I have tried some plugins like etheratom (With lots of smartcontracts the program brokes), Intellij solidity plugin (In this one I don't know how to compile and deploy the contracts).

EDIT:

And I missed a very important feature that I want and that dosen't have any IDE that I have tryed.

- Give the exact position of errors like `invalid opcode`

I have serched a lot and I didn't find anything.

Comment: I found your question legible .. u will hv more upvotes sooner or later. 
:-)

Comment: Hello @david.t_92 , this is a 3-year-old question and I've recently started working on Solidity. I wanted to know which IDE you went with and how was your experiences so far?

Comment: @MehmedB Yes old question, I think that right now there are better programing languages for smart contracts.

I have used the following online IDE: https://remix.ethereum.org/

Answer (score 4):

Since Solidity is relatively young a lot of actions has to be done manually for setting up compiling and deployment process.

In fact there are tools to help you the processes

1. [Truffle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle) is a development environment and testing framework and asset aiming to make **life as an Ethereum developer easier**.
2. [Ganache-CLI](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) or [Ganache-GUI](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache) - Ethereum RPC client for testing and development.
3. [Intellij-Solidity](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9475-intellij-solidity)   is a plugin for Itnellij-based IDEs offers syntax highlighting, code formatting and autocomplete for Solidity files.

---

[Solidity Development: Setting up environment](https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-development-setting-up-environment-611c4bc2530b)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, as a previous user of Atom and IntelliJ, I will recommend **VSCode**.

I find these extentions really great for developing smart contracts with solidity on VSCode:

1. *Material Icon Theme*, for better distinguish folders and files;
2. *solidity* or *solidity-solhint*, Ethereum Solidity Language for Visual Studio Code;
3. *Trailing spaces*, highlight trailing spaces and delete them;
4. *Rainbow Brackets*, for cool brackets; :)
5. *Indent rainbow*, for better and easier indentation
6. *GitHistory* and *GitLens*.

You should have a better experience with that and then try to test the code in the plugin.